# Missing token endpoint URI. Google API Gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api

I'm trying to list all the emails from inbox in a ruby on rails app I have the login and authentication working with **omniauth-google-oauth2** now I want to list all the inbox messages so in my controller:

**home_controller.rb** I have this:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

def index
   if session[:user_id] 
    client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(access_token: session[:access_token])

    client.expires_in = Time.now + 1_000_000

    service = Google::Apis::GmailV1::GmailService.new

    service.authorization = client

    @labels_list = service.list_user_labels('me')
   else
    puts "ERROR !!!"
   end
  end
end
```

and in my **User** model I have this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
   user.provider = auth.provider
   user.uid = auth.uid
   user.name = auth.info.name
   user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
   user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
   user.save!
  end
 end
end
```

I have this error:

```
Missing token endpoint URI.
```

I dont know how to resolve this I tried everything in stackoverflow and documentation.

Regards and thanks for your time guys !